# Converge Test on the series $\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2n+n^3}{3-4n}\right)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

I want to show, that $a:=\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{2n+n^3}{3-4n}\right)^n$ is not converging, because $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}(a)\neq 0 \; (*)$. Therefore, the series can't be absolute converge too.

Firstly, I try to simplify the term. After that I want to find the limit.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find any good equation with that I can clearly show $(*)$.
\begin{align}
\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{2n+n^3}{3-4n}\right)^n&=\left (\dfrac{\not{n}\cdot (2+n^2)}{\not n \cdot (\frac{3}{n}-4)}\right)^n\\
&=\left(\dfrac{2+n^2}{\frac 3n-4}\right)^n\\
&= \cdots
\end{align}

How to go on?

Comment: Do you know the root test?

Comment: You mean that we need to show, that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\mid a_n \mid}<1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that

$$\sum_0^\infty a_n <\infty \implies a_n \to 0$$

therefore if $a_n \not \to 0$ the series can’t converge.

In that case for $n\ge 3$ we have

$$\left|\dfrac{2n+n^3}{3-4n}\right|=\dfrac{2n+n^3}{4n-3}>\dfrac{n^3}{4n}=\frac{n^2}4\ge2$$

and then

$$|a_n|=\left|\dfrac{2n+n^3}{3-4n}\right|^n\ge 2^n$$

Refer also to the related:

- [Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\ln(n)$ converge or diverge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2701344/505767)

Comment: Therfore it is $\neq 0$ and divergent. Is that enough for a formal proof?

Comment: @Doesbaddel Absolutely, it is the first test to do for any series!

Comment: Alright, I was a bit confused, because it looked so simple.

Comment: @Doesbaddel Here is the formal [**proof**](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2701349/505767). Recall that it is a **necessary condition** but not sufficient, that is if $a_n \to 0$ we cannot conlcude that $\sum a_n$ converges but if $a_n \not \to 0$ we can conclude that the series doesn't converges.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at the proof. Btw, I tried to prove it by my own with the help of the root test. Is it correct?

Comment: @Doesbaddel You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit confused by your choice of notation for it seems like you write that a series diverges if its limit is not $0$ what is not true. So i think you mean that we want to show that

$$\frac{(2n+n^3)^n}{(3-4n)^n}\not\rightarrow 0$$

as $n\rightarrow \infty$ for this implies that the series does not converge. Note also that

$$\left(\frac{2+n^2}{3/n-4}\right)^n\neq \frac{2^n+n^{2n}}{3^n\cdot (1/n)^n-4^n}$$

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream

Instead what can you say about

$$\frac{2n+n^3}{3-4n}\rightarrow ?$$

as $n\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: I wanted to express, that if the series is a nullsequence for $n \to \infty$, then it is not converging. Is that right? It is obvious, that $\frac{2n+n^3}{3-4n} \to \infty$ but how do I show formally, that the same is true for $\left(\frac{2n+n^3}{3-4n}\right)^n$?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the term null sequence, what is that?

Comment: Well $\left|\frac{2n+n^3}{3-4n}\right| = \frac{2n+n^3}{4n-3}$ if $n\geq 1$. Now if $p>1$ then which of the following holds: $p<p^n$ or $p\geq p^n$

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Null_Sequence_(Analysis)

Comment: If the series converges to $0$ then it converges and hence does not diverge

Comment: $p<p^n$ should be true. Yeah, sry I meant that it is not a nullsequence.

Comment: Therefore $\left|\frac{2n+n^3}{3-4n}\right|^n$ satisfies...?

Comment: $\left|\frac{2n+n^3}{3-4n}\right|^n > 1$ Sry, that it took so long, my Laptop ran out of energy. I literally ran into my home to answer your question.

Comment: I was thinking $\left|\frac{2n+n^3}{3-4n}\right|^3>\left|\frac{2n+n^3}{3-4m}\right|$

Comment: Oh, sry I misunderstood that. So I should go on with $\left|\frac{2n+n^3}{3-4n}\right| < \left|\frac{2n+n^3}{3-4n}\right|^n$?

Comment: yes and since the left-hand side is unbounded so must the right-hand side be

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense and helps me to solve it. However, stay tuned, because I may try to do the root test as @Clarinetist suggested.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\underbrace{\dfrac{2n+n^3}{3-4n}}_{a_n}\right)^n$

Root test: Prove:$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\mid a_n \mid}<1 \implies a_n \text{ is absolute converging.}$

\begin{align}
&\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\left( \dfrac{2n+n^3}{3-4n}\right)^n} \\
=&\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}=\frac{2n+n^3}{3-4n}\\
=&\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}=\dfrac{n(n^2+2)}{n(\frac 3n-4)}\\
=&\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}=\dfrac{\overbrace{n^2+2}^{\infty}}{\underbrace{\frac 3n-4}_{0}}\\
=&\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}(a_n)=\infty\\&
\implies a_n \text{ and } \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{2n+n^3}{3-4n}\right)^n \text{ are not absolute convergent.}
\end{align}

I just noticed, that this would only prove absolute convergence and not convergence.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n \ge 4$.

$|a_n|:=\left |\dfrac{n^3+2n}{4n-3}\right |^n \gt$

$\left (\dfrac{n^3}{4n}\right )^n \ge n^n.$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |a_n| \not = 0$.

Hence the series does not converge.